# how to deobfuscation of android project

Tags: android, reverse-engineering, deobfuscation

I decompiled an apk but I got 2000+ errors in the resulted project. I think that it is due to obfuscation. Can any one please guide me how to deobfuscate this project or another way to get error free source code?

As in the following decompiled class i am getting error at break Missing_BLOCK_LABEL

```
public String FunTargetBetData(String s)
{
    String s1 = "";
    URL = ipList.SetUrlPath();
    if (URL == "" || s == "")
    {
        break MISSING_BLOCK_LABEL_134;
    }
    SoapPrimitive soapprimitive;
    try
    {
        SoapObject soapobject = new SoapObject("http://tempuri.org/", "FTargetBetDataProcess");
        soapobject.addProperty("indatastr", Encrypt(s, encryptKey));
        SoapSerializationEnvelope soapserializationenvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(110);
        soapserializationenvelope.dotNet = true;
        soapserializationenvelope.setOutputSoapObject(soapobject);
        soapserializationenvelope.encodingStyle = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/";
        (new HttpTransportSE(URL, TimeOut)).call("http://tempuri.org/AndIService1/FTargetBetDataProcess", soapserializationenvelope);
        soapprimitive = (SoapPrimitive)soapserializationenvelope.getResponse();
    }
    catch (SocketTimeoutException sockettimeoutexception)
    {
        sockettimeoutexception.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("FunTargetBetData SocketTimeoutException", sockettimeoutexception.toString());
        return "";
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        exception.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("FunTargetBetData Error", exception.toString());
        return "";
    }
    if (soapprimitive == null)
    {
        break MISSING_BLOCK_LABEL_134;
    }
    s1 = soapprimitive.toString();
    s1.trim();
    return s1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To deobfuscate you need mapping.txt file that is generated while obfuscating. So, you can only do it if you have mapping file generated.

Comment: Thanks Mr Bishwash but I don't have mapping.txt file. Is there any other way?

Comment: As i know there's no way you can deobfuscate without mapping.txt.